# independent vs dependent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I'm reading Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra. In section 1.3 he starts with 3 vectors:

$\vec{u}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$
$\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$
$\vec{w}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

These are independent and I can see that geometrically.

Then he turns $\vec{w}$ into $\vec{w}^* = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Now the 3 vectors are dependent because $\vec{w}^*$ lies in the plane of the other 2.  I can see this geometrically as well.

Then he goes on to state that the important point is that the new vector $\vec{w}^*$ is a linear combination of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{w}$:

$\vec{u} + \vec{v} + \vec{w}^* = 0$ because $ \vec{w}^* = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = -\vec{u} - \vec{v}$.

1. $\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{w}$ are **independet**. No combination except $0\vec{u} + 0\vec{v} + 0\vec{w}$ gives $\vec{b} = 0$.
2. $\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{w}^*$ are **dependet**. Other combinations (specificaly $\vec{u} + \vec{v} + \vec{w}^*$) give $\vec{b} = 0$.

My question is why, algebraically, is 2. true?

Comment: If $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ are vectors of $R^n$, they're dependent (by definition) if $c_1*\vec{u}+c_2*\vec{v}+c_3*\vec{w} = \vec{0}$ for some $c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ (where each $c_n$ is non-zero). Specifically in your example, we have $1*\vec{w}^* - 1*\vec{u}-1*\vec{v} = \vec{0}$, but it need not be the case that theses coefficients are one.

Answer (score 0):

If the vectors are dependent, you can express one as a linear combination of the others.  Suppose you have $au+bv+cw = 0$.  You can try to solve this equation for one of the vectors, say $w$ to get $$w = \frac{-a}{c}u + \frac{-b}{c}v.$$

But see that this works only if $c\neq 0$.  As long as one of $a, b,$ or $c$ is nonzero, you can solve for one of the vectors.  If they are all $0$, then you can't.

Answer (score 0):

we assume $$\alpha[1,-1,0]+\beta[0,1,-1]+\gamma[0,0,1]=[0,0,0]$$
from the first equation we get $$\alpha=0$$ and it follows $$\beta=0$$ (second equation) and last but not least $$\gamma=0$$

Comment: Do you mean $\alpha\begin{bmatrix}1, -1, 0]\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: yes that is what i mean